On two-sided Laplace transform in probability; how to show it is injective?
I am studying a theorem in probability that the Laplace transform of a (nonnegative) random variable determines the law of that random variable, which is equivalent to its injectivity. The book (Measure theory, Probability and Stochastic processes by Le Gall) only treats Laplace transforms of nonnegative random variables, but since the moment generating function (mgf) is in fact the two sided Laplace transform evaluated at $-t$ (i.e. $L_X(t)=m_X(-t)$, where $L_X$ denotes the two sided Laplace transform), and since mgfs exist for arbitrary sign random variables, I wonder how to extend the result to say the two-sided Laplace transform is also injective.
I will omit the theorem and its proof here as given in the book, since it would mean a lot of typing. But the relevant part of the proof of the theorem is that we are considering the set  $H$ of functions consisting of $\psi_\lambda(x)=e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\geq 0$ and $\lambda\geq 0$. We extend the functions by continuity so they are defined on all of $[0,\infty]$, namely we put $\psi_\lambda(\infty)=0$ if $\lambda>0$ and $\psi_0(\infty)=1$. Having a compact set $[0,\infty]$, we can apply the Stone-Weierstrass theorem to say that $H$ is dense in $C([0,\infty],\mathbb R)$. This allows us later in the proof to conclude that $\mathbb E[\phi(X)]=\mathbb E[\phi(Y)]$ for every $\phi\in C([0,\infty],\mathbb R)$, which establishes that the law of $X$ and $Y$ equal since they are determined by the expectation of $\phi(X)$ and $\phi(Y)$ as $\phi$ varies in the space of all continuous, compact support functions from $[0,\infty]$ to $\mathbb R$.
How would one go about showing the two-sided Laplace transform is injective? I guess one would like to consider $[-\infty,\infty]$ and apply the Stone-Weierstrass theorem also, but I'm unsure how one would modify $H$. I prefer ways without complex analysis, but if its inevitable, then I accept those too.

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34956/proof-that-moment-generating-functions-uniquely-determine-probability-distributi, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84219/whether-distributions-with-the-same-moments-are-identical  and search that site!

Assume that $L(s)=\int_Re^{sx}\mu(dx)<\infty$ on $(a,b)$ with $-\infty\leq a<b\leq \infty.$ We want to prove that the knowledge of $L$ gives the knowledge of the positive measure $\mu.$ For this we prove first that $L$ is real-analytic on $(a,b)$ ( that means that for any $s_0\in (a,b))$ there exists $R_{s_0}>0$ such that $h\mapsto L(s_0+h)$ is expandable as a power series with $R_{s_0}$ radius of convergence. Next we take $[a_1,b_1]\subset (a,b).$ By compacity there are a finite number of $s\in [a_1,b_1]$ such that the discs of the complex plane centered in $s$ with radius $R_s$ cover $[a_1,b_1]$. As a consequence $L$ is analytic in their union $U$. Similarly $L$ is analytic in the strip $a<\Re s<b$ and  therefore is uniquely determined by its restriction to $[a_1,b_1].$ To conclude, take an arbitrary $a<s_0<b$ and consider the bounded positive measure $\mu_0(dx)=e^{xs_0}\mu(dx)$ with Fourier transform $t\mapsto L(s_0+it)$. Since $L$ is known, then this FT is known and by a L'evy Theorem $\mu_0$ and $\mu$ are known.
